# parsing get RSS feed with geotag data

Tags: java, android, rss, xml-parsing

I am still learning how to parse different XML feeds, so I was wondering how will one go about parsing an XML feed like the one below. is it possible to parse this without knowing the different XMl tags? Any steps to this, links or tutorial will be helpful.

http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/eqs1hour-M1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <channel>
    <title>USGS M 1+ Earthquakes</title>
    <description>Real-time, worldwide earthquake list for the past hour</description>
    <link>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/</link>
    <dc:publisher>U.S. Geological Survey</dc:publisher>
    <pubDate>Wed, 16 Nov 2011 11:47:10 GMT</pubDate>

    <item>
      <pubDate>Wed, 16 Nov 2011 11:41:25 GMT</pubDate>
      <title>M 1.1, Central California</title>
      <description>November 16, 2011 11:41:25 GMT</description>
      <link>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/recenteqsus/Quakes/nc71682246.php</link>
      <geo:lat>37.5637</geo:lat>
      <geo:long>-118.8648</geo:long>
      <dc:subject>1</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>pasthour</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>4.60 km</dc:subject>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">nc71682246</guid>
    </item>
    <item>
      <pubDate>Wed, 16 Nov 2011 11:15:18 GMT</pubDate>
      <title>M 4.5, Kodiak Island region, Alaska</title>
      <description>November 16, 2011 11:15:18 GMT</description>
      <link>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/recenteqsww/Quakes/ak10358657.php</link>
      <geo:lat>57.6877</geo:lat>
      <geo:long>-153.8939</geo:long>
      <dc:subject>4</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>pasthour</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>39.50 km</dc:subject>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">ak10358657</guid>
    </item>

  </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 2):

For parsing RSS feeds you can get a look at ROME:

http://java.net/projects/rome

You'll also find useful info in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android